# How to write MongoDB query in core PHP with dynamic date variable?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have created query in mongoDB. In MongoChef this query produces more than 10 thousand records. Now I want to execute this query in PHP. So i don't know how to write query in php with dynamic dates? 
My query in mongoDB

```
    db.PMS.aggregate(
 [
    { $match: { "EventTS":{$gt:new Date("2015-01-01")}}},
    ]
);
```

Now I tried to convert in PHP with pass dynamic date variable

```
    <?php    
$mongo = new MongoClient();    
$database = $mongo->securens_final;
$collection = $database->PMS;    
$start_date  = new MongoDate(strtotime('2015-01-01 00:00:00'));    
$pipeline = [
    [
        '$match' => [
            'EventTS' => ['$gt', $start_date]
        ]
    ]
];

$cursor = $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cursor);exit;
?>
```

After use this query i got response like this

```
    Array
(
    [waitedMS] => 0
    [result] => Array
        (
        )

    [ok] => 1
)
```

I don't know what is my mistake. Can any one suggest me how to slove this probelm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cursor` does not contain any data, it fetches data as you need it (for instance as you iterate through results). If you want all the data upfront you need to use `$data = iterator_to_array($cursor)`.

Comment: Ah, you have an error in pipeline, `'EventTS' => ['$gt', $start_date]` should be `'EventTS' => ['$gt' => $start_date]` (so `=>` instead of `,`)